# Rect and RectF in Android SDK

Tags: android, android-canvas, rect

What is the difference between Rect and RectF in the Android SDK?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Using `Rect` you define its edges using integers and using `RectF` they are defined as floats.

Looking at them more carefully I have spotted a few differences actually. I will only list what one implementation has more compared to the other one.

**Rect**

- [equals(Object obj)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) (for some reason it has its own implementation of equals)
- [exactCenterX()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#exactCenterX())
- [exactCenterY()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#exactCenterY())
- [flattenToString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#flattenToString())
- [toShortString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#toShortString())
- [unflattenFromString(String str)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#unflattenFromString(java.lang.String))

**RectF**

- [round(Rect dst)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF.html#round(android.graphics.Rect))
- [roundOut(Rect dst)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF.html#roundOut(android.graphics.Rect))
- [set(Rect src)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF.html#set(android.graphics.Rect))

So apparently there are some differences.

Comment: Yep one is defined with int http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html the other with float http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF.html. a part form that I don't know of any difference which begs the question why create 2 separate classes for that ^^

Comment: @JasonRogers I agree that it is somewhat funny.

Comment: I actually went to check the documentation to see if one didn't inherit the other with a bit of casting but not even that lol

Comment: @JasonRogers apparently there are some differences! I have listed them in my answer.

Answer (score 17):

Rect is final, RectF can be extended